# Where should I put generated Python srv

Tags: ros, rospy, rosservice, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked for it in the tutorials and online but I didn't find anything helpful. After uncommenting the line srv_gen in CMakeFiles.txt and running rosmake, some files are generated including headers for C++ put in include folder and Python scripts which are put into the folder packagename/src/packagename. The generated Python module's name was _myServiceMessagesFile.py for myServiceMessagesFile.srv being my service's messages declaration file that I put in packagename/srv.
Then the tutorial says to use "import myServiceMessagesFile.srv" which doesn't work.

I solved this problem by taking the generated .py file from packagename/src/packagename folder and putting it in the same folder as my Python script (for example packagename/scripts) needing this messages, but I feel that this method is more a dirty fix than an elegant solution.

I work with ros groovy and rosbuild. Can somebody give me some hints on what to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167986/where-should-i-put-generated-python-srv/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't have to move the generated service files.

Are you following the rosbuild version of the [python service and client tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python))?

Your import should be:

```
from mypackage.srv import *
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-03**:
yes and somehow it doesn't find it.
ImportError: No module named GetMeasures.srv

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-03**:
The correct form for this import is

```
from [package].srv import [service]
```

.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-03**:
Thanks. I somehow got confused in the tutorial ending up using myServiceMessagesFile.srv instead of  package.srv